# sql.DB.Query "expected 0 arguments" when using "?" placeholder

Tags: mysql, go

I am interacting with a MySQL database in golang using `database/sql` with the `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` driver

I associate tags to articles with a table `article_to_tag` which associates an article ID with a tag ID, and find articles with certain tags using a Toxi solution found toward the bottom of [this](http://howto.philippkeller.com/2005/04/24/Tags-Database-schemas/) article

This snippet is supposed to query my database for all articles associated with all tags in the array `itags`

```
    s := "SELECT a.* " +
        "FROM article_to_tag at, articles a, tags t " +
        "WHERE t.ID = at.TagID " +
        "AND a.ID = at.ArticleID " +
        "AND (t.Name IN ('?'" + strings.Repeat(",'?'", len(itags)-1) + ")) " +
        "GROUP BY a.ID " +
        "HAVING COUNT(a.ID)=" + strconv.Itoa(len(itags)) + ";"
    fmt.Println(s)
    rows, err := db.Query(s, itags...)
```

This builds the following string when querying for 2 tags, but querying with that string returns an error: `sql: expected 0 arguments, got 2`

```
SELECT a.*
FROM article_to_tag at, articles a, tags t
WHERE t.ID = at.TagID
AND a.ID = at.ArticleID
AND (t.Name IN ('?','?'))
GROUP BY a.ID HAVING COUNT(a.ID)=2;
```

Why is the query ignoring the `?` placeholder, and how else should I go about building the query safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the single quotes. When you use a placeholder, place it unquoted. With the quotes it's just a string.